# How to create a Twilio channel from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm coding an app that must create a chat channel when some conditions are fulfilled after the user updates a database table (I need to create a chat channel from the server side).

I'm using Node.js from AWS Lambda and `twilio-chat`. But I'm unable to create the client. Here is my code:

```
const Twilio = require('twilio-chat');

var chatClient = Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token)
```

I'm getting the following error:
`Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined`

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: check this https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-js/blob/master/lib/tokenprovider.js

Comment: The link you provided is for getting the access token. I'm getting the token just fine. My problem is that I'm unable to create an instance of the chat client with it

Comment: what about `var chatClient = new Twilio.Chat.Client(token);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The twilio-chat module is for use in the client side and uses browser websockets to connect to the Twilio Chat service. It is not build for server side use.

To create a channel from the server side you should use the [Twilio Node.js module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) and the [Twilio Chat REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest). You can [create a channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels#code-create-a-channel) like this:

```
var accountSid = 'your_account_sid';
var authToken = 'your_auth_token';
var serviceSid = 'your_chat_service_sid';

var Twilio = require('twilio').Twilio;

var client = new Twilio(accountSid, authToken);
var service = client.chat.services(serviceSid);

service.channels.create({
    friendlyName: 'MyChannel'
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.